# Link an externally defined static function in C++ Application code

Tags: c++, c

I have a set of pre defined C source code files that declares defines a lot of static functions - they are just coded up in .c files and not declared in any .h headers file.

Now I am trying to make use of those functions in my C++ application code:

```
Cmethods.c

static int amethod(int oppcheck)
{
}
```

A library is created using the C source code files:

```
$ nm --demangle userlib.a | grep amethod
00000000000001b6 t amethod

CppApp.h
extern "C" { int amethod(int oppcheck); }

CppApp.cpp
#include "CppApp.h"

voit callme()
{
amethod(check);
}
```

However during compilation ensuring that userlib.a is linked I get below error:

```
: undefined reference to `amethod'

$ nm --demangle userappcode.a | grep amethod
00000000000001b6 t amethod
                 U amethod
```

My further findings is that for functions in C source code files if declared in C header files - the linker error for them never occurs.

Note I cannot touch the C source code files - they are provided by third party community and we cannot break the license.

How can I resolve the issue

Comment: Please **edit your question** to give additional context and motivation. How did you get these set of C source files? Why are you forbidden to touch them? What will happen if you did touch them, or transform them somehow? Why are these functions `static`?

Comment: Without at least some motivation and context, your question is unclear. You want to use the C programming language against its specification and semantics. You should explain why you want to do so.

Comment: Updated the question with license and copyright terms of C source code

Comment: But who give you that code and what for? Perhaps you are not even allowed to *compile* that code, and probably not allowed to *redistribute* the binary... And you don't explain what license do you have...

Comment: *we cannot break the license.* Yet you appear to be asking how you can break the license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a set of pre defined C source code files that declares defines a lot of static functions.
>
> Now I am trying to make use of those functions in my C++ application code:

Remove the `static` from those functions you want to call from some other [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

If you cannot do that, you can't use these functions from outside. And the compiler could even optimize them to the point of removing them from your object file.

(a dirty trick that I do not recommend could be to compile that C code with `gcc -Dstatic=` to have the preprocessor replace `static` by nothing)

> Note I cannot touch the C source code files.

Then your task is impossible.

You could "augment" the translation units, perhaps by appending to them a *public* (non `static`) function calling the `static` one. For example, you might compile something like

```
// include the original C code with only `static` 
#include "Cmethods.c"
// code a public wrapper calling the static method
extern int public_amethod(int oppcheck);
int public_amethod(int oppcheck) { return amethod(oppcheck); }
```

> Note I cannot touch the C source code files - they are provided by third party community and we cannot break the license -

It looks like you might not be legally allowed to compile that code, or that you cannot distribute its object file. **There are no technical tricks to overcome a legal prohibition.** If that goes in court, you'll probably lose!

Your issue is not technical, but social and legal. You may need a lawyer. You could also talk with the provider of the original code, and ask him if you are allowed to do what you want.

<sup>(without more motivation and context, your question looks weird)</sup>

Comment: I tried to do that but I get error: redefinition of functions and data structures - I think then only option remains that I need to remove the static declartion

Comment: Do you realize that you might be *stealing* that code? Are you aware of the possible consequences? It looks like your manager is asking you to steal an apple, and you are stupidly complying. Don't act as a slave, you are a responsible person.

Answer (score 1):

If you defined `amethod` with `static`, then the function will have a internal linkage which means you can't link this function from other source files.

> internal linkage.
>
> The name can be referred to from all scopes in the
> current translation unit. Any of the following names declared at
> namespace scope have internal linkage
>
> variables, functions, or function templates declared static
>
> non-volatile non-inline (sinceC++17) const-qualified variables
> (including constexpr) that aren'tdeclared extern and aren't previously
> declared to have external linkage.
>
> data members of anonymous unions

Answer (score 1):

`static` functions in C and static member functions in C++ are two different things. In C, a static function it is limited to its translation unit and invisible outside, this essential means object file(.o/.obj).

In C++, `static` can also apply to member functions and data members of classes. A static data member is also called a "class variable", while a non-static data member is an "instance variable".

Answer (score 0):

you might not touch the C source but a hacky solution is to #include it into a different translation unit with functions that forward the statics. This is not something I would recommend as a general answer but ...

file1.c:

```
static void function1(int)
{ ...}
```

file2.c:

```
#include "file1.c"

void fwd_function1(int x)
{
  function1(x);
}
```

Comment: exactly what I suggested in my answer